# Re-building ng-admin after editing source code

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack, ng-admin

I made some modification in the [ng-admin](https://github.com/marmelab/ng-admin) source code, so I need to rebuild it using [webpack](http://webpack.github.io/).

I installed all node modules from the package.json with `$ npm install`
And then ran `webpack -d` which used the [webpack.config.js](https://github.com/marmelab/ng-admin/blob/master/webpack.config.js).
I removed the `, exclude: /node_modules[\\\/](?!admin-config)/` because I need to rebuild admin-config too.

So now I have all the js, css and map files,
but when I try to run the application I get this error:

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ng-admin due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ui.select due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ui.select' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

I made sure ui.select is installed as a node module.

What went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Well...
I had a node_modules folder inside the ng-admin folder which was inside another node_modules folder itself.

```
+ project
| index.html
| admin.js
| + node_modules
  | + ng-admin
    | + node_modules
      ...
```

I got rid of the parent node_modules folder, changed the js paths in my index of course, and everything builds correctly now.